# Thirdweb error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks error

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapps

So I have this code:

```
import { ThirdwebSDK } from "@thirdweb-dev/sdk";
import { ConnectWallet, useAddress } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";

export default function DonationPage() {
    let address = useAddress()

     async function sendCoins() {
        try {
            let random = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
        // get a signer from somewhere (createRandom is being used purely for example purposes)
        // get an instance of the SDK with the signer already setup
        const sdk = ThirdwebSDK.fromSigner(signer || random, "mainnet");
        try {
            if (selectedCoin == 'eth') {
                await sdk.wallet.transfer(CORPORATE_WALLET || "0x", donationAmount);
            } else {
                // const decimals = await contract.erc20..call()
                // const amount = new BigNumber(donationAmount * (10 ** decimals))
                const contract = await sdk.getContract(crypto.find((coin) => coin.id == selectedCoin)?.contract_address || '0x');

                let balance = await contract.erc20.balance()
                let allowance = await contract.erc20.allowance(address || '0x')

                // console.log('balance', balance.value)
                // console.log('allowance', allowance.value)

                if(donationAmount + Number(balance.displayValue) > Number(allowance.displayValue)) {
                    await contract.erc20.setAllowance(address || '0x', donationAmount + Number(balance.displayValue))
                }
                await contract.erc20.transferFrom(address || '0x',CORPORATE_WALLET || '0x', donationAmount);

            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            alert(error.message)
        }
    }

    return (<>...</>)

}
```

So i'm using ConnectWallet button to get address and using TrustWallet for this, and trying to transfer tokens from 'address' to a corporate wallet, with a specified donation amount.

However, I receive this error "Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined".

Here are 3 failed transactions:

1. 0x9cc1aa8199675ca31eef0f1f3f2985260cd4ee55155e91eab34dcc4899ac8ab1
2. 0xa134c2eb8c4487f7bab049ca10a9abccb60bd107432131754c14062000050e3d
3. 0x9b630249e6129ce97b003daa4bfe672bdb1bd8c7a57fb0912d3b45aeec19659d

There seems to be no documentation on this online, and ChatGPT won't help either. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: try to pay more gas maybe to get mined quickly?

Comment: I think you need put gas manually in your code ?